# Running unicorn and nginx on different servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, reverse-proxy, unicorn

Most of the tutorials out there show how to configure nginx web server as a proxy to a unicorn ruby application server when they are on the same server; a result is that they both communicate via unix sockets. How can I configure both of them if they are on different servers.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unicorn [designed](http://unicorn.bogomips.org) to serve fast clients only:

> unicorn is an HTTP server for Rack applications designed to only serve
>   fast clients on low-latency, high-bandwidth connections and take
>   advantage of features in Unix/Unix-like kernels. Slow clients should
>   only be served by placing a reverse proxy capable of fully buffering
>   both the the request and response in between unicorn and slow clients.

How does it work within load balancing between multi nodes environment? The answer is to have application nodes *Nginx+Unicorn* (connect via Unix Domain Socket) and top level Nginx as load balancer on separate node.

Answer (score 0):

The basic setup is as follows:

In your unicorn config you'll want to listen to a TCP port rather than a unix socket:

```
listen 80, :tcp_nopush => true
```

Likewise, in your Nginx configuration simply proxy requests to a remote server:

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;

    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;
    server backend3.example.com down;
    server backend4.example.com;
}
```

You should also checkout http://unicorn.bogomips.org/examples/nginx.conf for unicorn-tailored nginx configuration.